# RegExp for file endings in java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

How to write a regexp that validate a string for *.fileending like:

```
*.java; *.xml; ....
```

I want to have something like validate if the pattern is `*.<sometext>;` and so on....

The string can be like this:

```
*.java;   *.xml; *.c;
```

Now i want to validate that the string consist of `*.anyending;` and multiple patters and so on..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using something like the following pattern:

```
"(\\*\\.[a-z]+;\\s*)+"
```

This matches, one or more times:

- Starting with `*` (`\\*`)
- Followed by a period (`\\.`)
- Followed by one or more lowercase letters (`[a-z]+`)
- Followed by a semicolon (`;`)
- Followed by zero or more whitespace characters (`\\s*`).

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to allow multi patters with either lower OR uppercases ? Like;  string:   *.JAVA; *.xml;  ??

Comment: Change `[a-z]` to `[A-Za-z]+` if you want to allow `java`, `JAVA` or `JaVa` or `([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)` if you don't want `JaVa`.

Comment: Checkout the [Java Pattern docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) You can match word chars [a-zA-Z_0-9] with \w and it's all explained there. Note that to get "\w" in a regex pattern, you'll need to escape the '\' char so it becomes "\\w".

Comment: If this is to validate a string, maybe it should be anchored to start and end of line: `"^\\s*(?:\\*\\.\\w+\\s*;\\s*)+$"`

Comment: Thanks all! but couldnt get ([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)  to work :( FIXED; forgot last ' + '